# Somehow I don't see a boot menu when trying to dual-boot with Windows 8. How to fix?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu on my laptop that comes with Windows 8 pre-installed. If I turn it on it just boots to Windows 8 and does not give me a dual boot choice, as I would have expected.

Like I now how to boot up to it but it takes forever. I boot it up from the bios.

Comment: Is this because of the problems with UEFI or whatever it is called, the secure boot

Comment: "Like I now how to boot up" - I don't get this part. You *do* get it to boot Ubuntu? How?

Answer (score 0):

open windows 8, then click on the battery icon in bottom right
go to more power options, then on left panel choose what closing the lid does (in case for laptop, i dont know what the options for desktop), uncheck the fast startup.

this will solve the issue.

just let me know if this doesnt solve the issue